# Jtidy StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in Jmeter

Tags: java, xpath, jmeter, jtidy, tag-soup

I want to retrieve content from a webpage using JMeter.
The data I'm looking for is inside a javascript block :

```
(...)
<map id="id1">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var name="Lionel Richie";
    var song="Hello";
    var lyrics="Is it me you're looking for ?";
  </script>
(...)
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var name="Waldo";
  </script>
</map>
(...)
```

Let's say I want the value of the `name` variable inside a script block in the map id=id1,
where there's **also** a `song` variable.

I use a XPath Extractor to get the script content (CSS/Jquery won't get the javascript content as it's not pure HTML) :

`.//map[@id='id1']/script[contains(.,'song')]`

XPath won't find the data because my HTML is dirty (some wild stuff with missing tag ends and so on...) so I need to clean it up using Jtidy (Use *"Tidy(tolerant parser)"* option)

**Remarks :**
- I do not own the webpage I'm processing. I have to deal with this hideous HTML.
- there are many `maps` elements in the webpage each of them having a script with a `song` variable : I can't directly use regexp (as far as I know)

**Problem :**

The problem is : my HTML contains weird international characters *wé hà bêêêê*... (yep, french, sorry about that)  and Jtidy doesn't handle properly this particular case : [bug #205 StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while lexing script content](https://sourceforge.net/p/jtidy/bugs/205/)

As a result Xpath extractor fails and my entire test plan is stuck.

I desgined a custom solution but I find it a bit complex.
Maybe I can handle this in a better way.

**My solution :**

I used tagsoup java library to clean HTML output and store it in a JMeter variable that is then processed through Xpath (tick "JMeter variable" option in "Apply to") and finally I used a regexp to get my Lionel Richie stuff working...

`JMeter
    |->HTTP Request
        |->BeanShell PostProcessor->tagsoup > var RESPONSE
        |->Xpath Extractor, Apply to var RESPONSE > var XPATH_OUTPUT
        |->Regular Expression Extractor, Apply to var XPATH_OUTPUT`

To get tagsoup working with JMeter, just put the jar in the lib directory, and then use a BeanShell PostProcessor.

BeanShell code used :

```
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.*;

// getting response data of previous sampler
String rep=prev.getResponseDataAsString();

XMLReader r = new Parser();
HTMLSchema theSchema = new HTMLSchema();
r.setProperty(Parser.schemaProperty, theSchema);
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);

XMLWriter x = new XMLWriter(w);
x.setPrefix(theSchema.getURI(), "");

r.setContentHandler(x);

r.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(rep)) );

String encodedRep=outStream.toString("UTF-8");

vars.put("RESPONSE", encodedRep);
```

Comment: You could try using Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) with the following regex:

> (?s)var name="([^"]+?)";.+?var song=

It uses single line mode:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#line_mode

See:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is way much simpler.